# Getting Total in all the Rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get total in all the rows using sqlite database.

**Query Used**

```
select id,price,sum(price) order by id
```

**Table Data**

```
ID PRICE 
1  100
2  200
3  300
```

**Expectation**

```
ID PRICE TOTAL
1  100   600
2  200   600
3  300   600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       price, 
       (select sum(price) from your_table) as sum
from your_table 
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent sqlite3 version (3.25 or newer), you can use window functions:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE prices(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, price INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO prices(price) VALUES (100), (200), (300);
sqlite> SELECT id, price, sum(price) OVER () AS total FROM prices ORDER BY id;
id          price       total     
----------  ----------  ----------
1           100         600       
2           200         600       
3           300         600
```